# Windows 10 user profile 5.4 GB normal?

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

I just noticed today that I have a user profile of 5.4 GB. Is it normal to have such a huge profile?

This is Windows 10, profile under System\Properties\Advanced.

Comment: Why do some people wear red shoes?  Whats normal for some, is not for others.

Comment: @Keltari: Your comment only makes sense if you assume that OP _already knows_ that the profile stores all of their personal files, and not just internal Windows data.

Comment: Yes, it's normal... also not sure why moderators have marked this as opinion-based, considering it's a fact the `%UserProfile%` directory will reach well over 10GB, let alone 5GB.  **Any that believe this question is opinion based, please execute the following powershell command:** `cd ~ ; $totalsize=[long]0;gci -File -r -fo -ea Silent|%{$totalsize+=$_.Length};$totalsize`

Comment: Asking if anything is normal is unanswerable.

Answer (score 3):

*Can* it be normal? Definitely! It all depends on what you as a user put in there. If you keep your movie collection in your profile, 2TB could be considered normal. Is it normal for a brand new, still unused profile? Probably not.

It's good to know what windows keeps in your profile. It's basically everything that's personal to you as a user such as:

- Your personal settings
- Your document libraries such as documents, videos, pictures, etc.
- Whatever data or cache your installed software decides to put there.
- Applications and apps that are installed in your user profile instead of the Program Files folder such as some versions of Chrome.